# ICalendar .ICS file DTStart seems not be interpreted the same by Google and Outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I create a .ics file with:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20220812T100000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20220812T103000
```

The goal is a meeting at 10AM London time (BST).

Send it to my work account (Outlook), personal UK account (Gmail 1) and personal IT account (Gmail 2).

When I open the attached .ics file in the emails I have a different Start (also End) meeting time depending from the account.

Outlook and Gmail 1 accounts are UK locale, both the emails are opened in the same PC (UK locale).
Gmail 2 account is IT and is opened on an Android tabled (IT locale).

**Outlook**:
[image]

and the Meeting is created in the calendar with the WRONG start time: 11.00.

**Gmail 1 (UK user)**:
[image]

and the meeting is created in the calendar with the CORRECT start time: 10:00.
(DTEnd has the same issue obviously)

**Gmail 2 (IT user)**:
No image but the meeting is set to be at 11:00 Italian time.
That is the CORRECT start time: 11AM in Italy -> 10AM in London.
(Italy is GMT+2 while UK is GMT+1 at this date).

I assume Outlook is not interpreting the time correctly.

1. Why Outlook get the wrong time?
2. How to solve this (the requirement is to use TimeZoneID, so I cannot use UTC date)?

### [EDIT]

This is the full .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
METHOD:REQUEST 
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN 
VERSION:2.0 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
DESCRIPTION:Alex meeting at 10 AM London 
DTSTAMP:20220811T080000Z 
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20220812T100000 
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20220812T103000  
LOCATION:London 
SEQUENCE:0 
STATUS:CONFIRMED 
SUMMARY:Alex meeting at 10 AM London 
TRANSP:OPAQUE 
UID:ccc1a025-c45b-3a05-9305-d5538e6660e4 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: how do you create the .ics file? if manually you'd need to add the `VTIMEZONE` component as the [RFC5545 section 3.2.19](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19) specifies `An individual "VTIMEZONE" calendar component MUST be specified for
 each unique "TZID" parameter value specified in the iCalendar object.`

Comment: I don't have access to the code anymore but the ICS was generated by the Ical.Net library. For a meeting Start (and End) you need to initialize a CalDateTime object passing a DateTime.  If you also pass a TZID parameter (optional) the DateStart and DateEnd are created within the TZID, otherwise them are UTC dates.  
The ICS file (posted in the question) is egnerated without "VTIMEZONE" component by the library. I read the specs and ... so confusing... I don't blame ICal.Net, MS or Google if one of them made a mistake or the "interpretation" of it.

Comment: So, I understood that to use TZID you MUST use VTIMEZONE component? 1 for DateStart and 1 for DateEnd ? 
It seems that for VTIMEZONE you need to provide a TZID along with offset and ... more info? If that is right what's the point to pass a TZID (I actually don't have the offset but only the TZID provided from the caller) ? 
I was given the permission to use UTC date.  
I was able to use the ICal.Net to create a CalDateTime object and get the calculated offset from that. Using that offset I calculated the start and end date in UTC and used the UTC syntax for DTSTART and DTEND. It works.

Comment: you only need to define the `TZID` via the `VTIMEZONE`. Once defined you can reuse it as many times as you want. For a valid example see [RFC 5545 section 4 - iCalendar Object Examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-146) the second example defines `TZID:America/New_York` and then refers to it for both DTSTART and DTEND.